# How to pass request attribute from one action to another in struts2

Tags: java, struts2, mapping

I am setting 2 attributes on submittion of action & in success i am redirecting to another action which just forwading to page
So in that page i am not able to get request attributes.

Following is the scenario:

```
 <action name="getanalyticscounts/*" 
            class="com.controller.GetAnalytics">
            <param name="mode">{1}</param>
            <result name="success" type="redirectAction">analytics</result>
            <result name="error"  type="redirectAction">analytics</result>
            <result name="input"  type="redirectAction">analytics</result>            
        </action>

<action name="analytics">
            <result>pages/analytics.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

I am setting values in GetAnalytics-execute method which returns success
so redirectAction takes to analytics
analytics simply gives analtics.jsp page
and here i am not able to access request attributes.

Please let me know is there any way to solve?

Thanks in advace

Comment: any reason to use the redirect result type as you can simply return the view?

Comment: Yes, @UmeshAwasthi is right. why do you need redirect action here and when you are redirecting to another action new action will be invoked so previous valuestack values no more available in redirected(new) action. Alternately you can use chain result type but not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

try this out :

The result tag in struts.xml :-

```
<action name="getanalyticscounts/*" class="com.controller.GetAnalytics">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">analytics</param>
        <param name="param1">${paramvalue1}</param>
        <param name="param2">${paramvalue2}</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

suppose you need to pass 'param1' & 'param2' in the request for that 'analytics' action.

```
<action name="analytics" class="com.SomeClass">
    <result>pages/analytics.jsp</result>
</action>
```

The class which is called after firing *analytics* action should have setter & getters for 
the parameters being passed.

This should work.